# Why "e.Account == null" after using OAuth2Authenticator for Google Drive API

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

My goal is to put files on a specific Google Drive. I manage to get the google login page, to log in successfully, but when the focus is back on my app, the e.Account is null.

A lot of people seem to have this issue, but didn't find any tips to get through

```
 var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId,
                String.Empty,
                DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
                new Uri("com.***.myapp:/oauth2redirect"),
                new Uri("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"),
                isUsingNativeUI: true);

                auth.Completed += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.IsAuthenticated) /*e.IsAuthenticated always false, and e.Account always null/*
                    {
                        
                    } 
                };
```

For me, this issue come from the redirect, like google authentication is ok, but my app don't receive the validation.

Thanks a lot for your help ! I am struggling with this for 2 days now ...

Comment: any special reason your not using the google .net client library?

Comment: remember IsAuthenticated  is used for identity not for Oauth2 which is authorization.  add a profile scope may give you identity but tbh i dont normally bother with identity when using Oauth2

Comment: @DaImTo I don't know, I tried lot of things, this one was the "best" for me, but I will try again with google library

What do you use to authenticate with OAuth2 pls ?

Comment: remember oauth2 is for authorization signin is for authentication its two different things.    Are you doing a web app or an installed app?

Comment: Installed app, I am quit lost now ahah, I need to understand the differences

Comment: @MaximeV - Any luck with this? I am facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to try the google .net client library this code should work.

```
var credential =   GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                             scopes,
                                                                             userName,
                                                                             CancellationToken.None,
                                                                             new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;

// Create the  Drive service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });

// Upload file Metadata
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
    Name = "Test hello uploaded.txt",
    Parents = new List() {"10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w"}
    };

string uploadedFileId;
// Create a new file on Google Drive
await using (var fsSource = new FileStream(UploadFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      // Create a new file, with metadata and stream.
      var request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, fsSource, "text/plain");
      request.Fields = "*";
      var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);

      if (results.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
         {
         Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");
         }

          // the file id of the new file we created
          uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
      }
```

Most of this code was ripped from my [Google drive upload tutorial](https://www.daimto.com/upload-file-to-google-drive/) That tutorial however uses service account authentication.  I have replated that in the code above with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker which is used for installed apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I will try this later in the day. Just to be sure, when i create a web application OAuth on my google cloud console, it's asked for a redirect url, do you now if i need to put something ? Thanks :)

Comment: run your code the first time.  You will get a redirect uri miss match error.  Just take that url and add it in Google cloud console. Its the easiest way to find it.   [How to fix redirect uri miss match error](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)